# Can you specify a type for a set() in a typespec?

Tags: erlang

I would like to specify a type that is just a set, i.e.:

```
-type itemset() :: set(integer()).
```

Is that possible in erlang?

Just curious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set is not a primitive type in Erlang, so there is no primitive type spec for it. However, if you have a module that defines and exports such a type then you can refer to it from another module.

For example, if the set you are referring to is the one defined in the `sets` module of `stdlib`, then you can use it like this:

```
-type itemset() :: sets:set(integer()).
```

Note the reference to the `sets` module.

You can also create your own definition of `set()` using `-type` and `-export_type` (if you need the type outside of the module). Check out section 7.3 here: http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/typespec.html
With that done, just replace `sets` with the module where your own definition of `set()` is.